# Is "Contents sold by weight not volume" Passive Voice or something else?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

On the packaging with milk powder, I saw the remark "Contents sold by weight not volume." if it was written "is sold" everything would be clear. How can this spelling be explained? Perhaps this grammatical construction has a name

Comment: There is no reason to think snippets written on the packaging are complete sentences.

Comment: "Contents are sold by weight, not volume."  The "are" is elided, not unusual in such a context.

Comment: @HotLicks So does this mean that “weight sold the contents” in the active, given that the contents were “sold by weight” in the passive? :) What's the active version? Inquiring minds want to know!

Comment: @tchrist - I don't think the contents are very active.

Answer (score 1):

> "Contents sold by weight not volume."
>   has several words missing. This is not unusual on packaging and in places where there is not a lot of space.

The full version is 
"**The** contents **of this pack are** sold [**by the manufacturer]** by weight not **by** volume."

It is therefore a passive.

Answer (score -1):

This is the passive voice, equivalent to "Balls kicked by footballer" or "Law passed by Parliament".

Adding "are" (as you suggest, but "contents" is plural) would make things a little clearer, yes!

Comment: It would be passive voice if there were a verb, but there is not. It is shorthand for a complete sentence. As a cyclist in the UK I often encounter signs that say "Cyclists Dismount". That is intended to be shorthand for the imperative "Cyclists, dismount!" or possibly "Cyclists must/should/ought to/would be well advised to dismount". To me it always evokes the mental response "No they don't! Just watch me!".

Comment: The sentence is in the passive voice, but *by weight* in it performs a very different role than *by footballer* or *by Parliament* in these examples. *Weight* would not be the subject of the corresponding active sentence. (That was the point of the joking comment by tchrist above.)